# Sql Exists vs MySql Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, exists

In MySql I can return (what is effectively) a boolean using this to determine whether a database exists by name.

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'MyDatabase')
```

What is the same in MS SQL?

Comment: EXISTS is part of MS SQL and if you want to check for a database by name, read the MS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-a-list-of-databases-on-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: `EXISTS` does the same on MySQL and TSQL/MSSQL (in this case).

Comment: I get: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.

Comment: `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do it this way:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)
 SELECT 1
ELSE
 SELECT 0
```

It's interesting that although the EXISTS function does return a boolean that can be tested by an IF, it can't be selected directly.

This doesn't work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1)
```

But this does:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1)
 SELECT 1
ELSE 
 SELECT 0
```

Weird.

EDIT:  On further reflection, I guess **MySQL** might treat `EXISTS()` like a function that returns a value, whereas **SQL Server** treats it as a conditional expression that either passes or fails but doesn't return a value.

So in **SQL Server**, trying to `SELECT` the result of an `EXISTS()` is like trying to `SELECT ('a' > 'b')`.   It can't do it.   I wonder what **MySQL** does if you try?

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE WHEN EXISTS()..`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: This is the best solution and closest to the code in MySQL.  It also works in MySQL -- it has the benefit of being standard SQL.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a boolean in t-sql. The closest is a bit which actually allows three values (0, 1 and NULL). If you want to select either 1 or 0 you can do this by converting count(*) to a bit. Any value other than 0 will be a 1.

```
select MyResult = convert(bit, count(*))
FROM information_schema.schemata
where SCHEMA_NAME = 'YourSchemaName'
```

Comment: I have a nit to pick...it's not exactly true that there's no such thing as a boolean, it's that there's no such datatype.  Try to create a WHERE clause like `WHERE 'hello'` and I believe the engine will complain about expecting a boolean.   : )

Comment: hehe the error message states that but you can't use anything in t-sql like a true boolean. The actual message there is "An expression of non-boolean type specified..." which means that the expression does not have a true or false result.